# What is 'Used so far' in Execution Overview tab in Developer Console?

Tags: developer-console, execution-overview

In following **Execution Overview**, **Used so far** column is 0 and **Request Total** is keeping track of the governor limits. I noticed some other logs and **Used so far** is always 0. Can any one please explain its purpose? If possible, please point me to the documentation. I always have trouble learning about Developer Console functionality. Either it is not documented properly or I'm looking at the wrong place.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first telling thing here is that you need to have the Apex Profiling level set to finest for that Tab to work.

The second part is if you fire up the Chrome Developer console when opening the debug log and switching to the Analysis perspective. It doesn't make any additional requests to populate the Limits tab.

This to me implies it is using the LIMIT_USAGE or LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS event data to populate that view. Maybe from `ApexCSIJsonServlet?extent=steps` as the extent=methods is probably for the Executed Units tab.

Test Anonymous Apex:

```
List<Account> accs = [Select Id from Account];
Integer count = [Select Count() from Account];
```

Filtered Log for LIMIT_USAGE: (Note the `SOQL|1|100`)

[image]

Resulting Limits tab.

[image]

I found that if I moved the selected line in the Execution log I could get the "Used so far" column to change. Before the first occurrence of the LIMIT_USAGE the value was 0. After it changed to 1.  The LIMIT_USAGE appeared within the SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN and SOQL_EXECUTE_END events.

This is actually pretty cool IMHO. You can select events up and down the debug log to see how far the limits have progressed so far in relation to the transaction total.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. This is really a very helpful feature.